# Convert NSPredicate to SQL

Tags: sql, objective-c, macos, cocoa, nspredicate

I need a class that I can just drop into my project send it a predicate as a parameter and have it return back an NSString of the SQL query it represents.

Something like below might be the prototype?

```
@interface PSPredicateToSQL : NSObject

+ (NSString *)SQLClauseForPredictate:(NSPredicate*) predicate;

@end
```

Does anyone know a class that does this, or how to go about doing this if not?

I need this for a search window I have implemented where the data for the search is stored in an SQLite database.

[image]

Comment: May I ask *why* you need this?

Comment: I have an SQLlite database in my program, I'm making a search window that uses the NSPredicateEditor, it has a function that returns the predicate.  If I return the predicateFormat I get (Last Opened Date == CAST(394908328.515259, "NSDate") OR Medical Record Number CONTAINS "" OR Medical Record Number ENDSWITH "" OR Last Opened Date < CAST(394908328.515259, "NSDate") OR Paitient Name BEGINSWITH[c] ""  which is not SQL friendly for searching the database.  I would have to manually go through that returned string and convert it to SQL syntax.

Comment: This project: https://gist.github.com/iluvcapra/5118789 claims to have a converter. Interestingly, the main function `NSString *SQLWhereClauseForPredictate(NSPredicate *predicate)` has the same typo "Predictate" as your suggested prototype :-)

Comment: actually that is not a coincidence, I actually copied it from that. Before asking here I always do my homework. That is a python (I think, or some other language) conversion though and I can't figure out how to convert that code to objective-c format (or for that matter) test if it even works at all.  I didn't notice he had a typo :P.  How can I test his code?

Comment: I don't see any Python code in that project, only Objective-C.

Comment: Could you by chance compile some code that uses that and send me a sample? I don't mind paying for help, I'm really lost on how to make that code work.  I try copying the code line by line into my project but get compile errors, not to mention some of it doesn't make sense.  He has functions that exist without any prototypes.

Comment: @JosephAstrahan: It's perfectly legal to have functions that haven't been previously declared; there are plenty of other problems with that code. I think the author just typed it directly into the Gist field without compiling or running it. It's a start, though, and it's definitely Objective-C (or maybe Objective-C++, given the filename extension), not Python.

Comment: I'll see what I can do, looks like I might have to make this class myself :(, well here goes.  I'll upload it to github later if I get it working to help anyone else with the issue.

Comment: I have finished the class and it works great now, if anyone would like to see what I did let me know.  I had to completely re-work that pseudo code from that example.

Comment: I added my answer of the working code I created that does the conversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally made my own class, hope this helps you guys out.

.H File

```
@interface PredicateToSQL : NSObject

+ (PredicateToSQL *) sharedObject;
- (NSString *) SQLFilterForPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate;
@end
```

.M File

```
#import "PredicateToSQL.h"

@implementation PredicateToSQL

static NSString *SQLNullValueString = @"NULL";

/* Implementation */
static PredicateToSQL *sharedObject;

+ (PredicateToSQL *) sharedObject
{
    return sharedObject;
}

+ (void) initialize
{
    sharedObject = [PredicateToSQL new];
}

- (NSString *)SQLExpressionForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
{
NSString     *retStr = nil;
NSDictionary *convertibleSetOperations = @{@"@avg" : @"avg",@"@max" : @"max",@"@min" : @"min",@"@sum" : @"sum",@"@distinctUnionOfObjects" : @"distinct" };

for (NSString *setOpt in [convertibleSetOperations allKeys])
 { if ([keyPath hasSuffix:setOpt])
    { NSString *clean = [[keyPath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:setOpt withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".." withString:@"."];
      retStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@(%@)",convertibleSetOperations[setOpt], clean];
     };
  };
if (retStr != nil) return(retStr);
return(keyPath);
}

- (NSString *) SQLSelectClauseForSubqueryExpression:(NSExpression *)expression
{
PSLog(@"SQLSelectClauseForSubqueryExpression not implemented");
return(nil);
}

- (NSString *) SQLLiteralListForArray:(NSArray *)array
{
NSMutableArray *retArray = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSExpression *obj in array) { [retArray addObject:[self SQLExpressionForNSExpression:obj]]; };
return([NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@)",[retArray componentsJoinedByString:@","]]);
}



- (NSString *) SQLFunctionLiteralForFunctionExpression:(NSExpression *)exp
{  
NSDictionary *convertibleNullaryFunctions = @{ @"now" : @"date('now')",@"random" : @"random()" };
NSDictionary *convertibleUnaryFunctions   = @{ @"uppercase:" : @"upper",@"lowercase:" : @"lower",@"abs:" : @"abs" };
NSDictionary *convertibleBinaryFunctions  = @{ @"add:to:"        : @"+" ,
                                               @"from:subtract:" : @"-" ,
                                               @"multiply:by:"   : @"*" ,
                                               @"divide:by:"     : @"/" ,
                                               @"modulus:by:"    : @"%" ,
                                               @"leftshift:by"   : @"<<",
                                               @"rightshift:by:" : @">>"
                                               };

if ([[convertibleNullaryFunctions allKeys] containsObject:[exp function]])
      { return(convertibleNullaryFunctions[[exp function]]);
       }
 else { if ([[convertibleUnaryFunctions allKeys] containsObject:[exp function]])
         { return([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@(%@)",convertibleUnaryFunctions[[exp function]],[self SQLExpressionForNSExpression:[exp arguments][0]]]);
          }
    else { if ([[convertibleBinaryFunctions allKeys] containsObject:[exp function]])
            { return([NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@ %@ %@)",[self SQLExpressionForNSExpression:[exp arguments][0]],convertibleBinaryFunctions[[exp function]],[self SQLExpressionForNSExpression:[exp arguments][1]]]);
             }
       else { PSLog(@"SQLFunctionLiteralForFunctionExpression could not be converted because it uses an unconvertible function");
             };
          };
       };
return(nil);
}

- (NSString *) SQLNamedReplacementVariableForVariable:(NSString *)var
{
//PSLog(@"SQLNamedReplacementVariableForVariable not implemented");
return(var);
}

/*
NSArray *temp = [gPatientDatabaseDictionary allKeysForObject:var];
NSString *key = [temp objectAtIndex:0];
return(key);
*/


- (NSString *)DatabaseKeyfor:(NSString *)obj
{
NSArray *keysForObj = [DatabaseDictionary allKeysForObject:obj];
if ([keysForObj count] > 0) return([keysForObj objectAtIndex:0]);
return(obj);
}



- (NSString *)SQLExpressionForLeftKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
{
NSString     *retStr = nil;
NSDictionary *convertibleSetOperations = @{ @"@avg" : @"avg",@"@max" : @"max",@"@min" : @"min",@"@sum" : @"sum",@"@distinctUnionOfObjects" : @"distinct" };

for (NSString *setOpt in [convertibleSetOperations allKeys])
 { if ([keyPath hasSuffix:setOpt])
    { NSString *clean = [[keyPath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:setOpt withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".." withString:@"."];
      retStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@(%@)",convertibleSetOperations[setOpt],clean];
     };
  };

if (retStr != nil) return([self DatabaseKeyfor:retStr]);
return([self DatabaseKeyfor:keyPath]);
}


- (NSString *) SQLConstantForLeftValue:(id) val
{
if (val == nil) return(SQLNullValueString);
if ([val isEqual:[NSNull null]]) return(SQLNullValueString);

if ([val isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
      { //PSLog(@"SQLConstantForLeftValue val %@",val);
        return([self DatabaseKeyfor:val]);
       }
 else { if ([val respondsToSelector:@selector(intValue)])
         { return([self DatabaseKeyfor:[val stringValue]]);
          }
    else { return([self SQLConstantForLeftValue:[val description]]);
          };
      };
return(nil);
}



-(NSString *)SQLExpressionForLeftNSExpression:(NSExpression *)expression
{
NSString *retStr = nil;

switch ([expression expressionType])
 { case NSConstantValueExpressionType: { retStr = [self SQLConstantForLeftValue:[expression constantValue]];
                                         //NSLog(@"LEFT  NSConstantValueExpressionType %@",retStr); // contains 'Patient Name' etc..
                                         break; }
        case NSVariableExpressionType: { retStr = [self SQLNamedReplacementVariableForVariable:[expression variable]];
                                         //NSLog(@"LEFT NSVariableExpressionType %@",retStr);
                                         break; }
         case NSKeyPathExpressionType: { retStr = [self SQLExpressionForLeftKeyPath:[expression keyPath]];
                                         //NSLog(@"LEFT NSKeyPathExpressionType %@",retStr); // first "Patient Name'
                                         break; }
        case NSFunctionExpressionType: { retStr = [self SQLFunctionLiteralForFunctionExpression:expression];
                                         //NSLog(@"LEFT NSFunctionExpressionType %@",retStr);
                                         break; }
        case NSSubqueryExpressionType: { retStr = [self SQLSelectClauseForSubqueryExpression:expression];
                                         //NSLog(@"LEFT NSSubqueryExpressionType %@",retStr);
                                         break; }
       case NSAggregateExpressionType: { retStr = [self SQLLiteralListForArray:[expression collection]];
                                         //NSLog(@"LEFT NSAggregateExpressionType %@",retStr);
                                         break; }
        case NSUnionSetExpressionType: { break; }
    case NSIntersectSetExpressionType: { break; }
        case NSMinusSetExpressionType: { break; }

 case NSEvaluatedObjectExpressionType: { break; } // these can't be converted 
           case NSBlockExpressionType: { break; }
        //case NSAnyKeyExpressionType: { break; }
  };
return retStr;
}



-(NSString *)SQLConstantForValue:(id) val
{
if (val == nil) return(SQLNullValueString);
if ([val isEqual:[NSNull null]]) return(SQLNullValueString);

if ([val isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
      { //NSLog(@"SQLConstantForValue val %@",val);
        return(val);
       }
 else { if ([val respondsToSelector:@selector(intValue)])
         { return([val stringValue]);
          }
    else { return([self SQLConstantForValue:[val description]]);
          };
      };
return(nil);
}



-(NSString *)SQLExpressionForNSExpression:(NSExpression *)expression
{
NSString *retStr = nil;

switch ([expression expressionType])
 { case NSConstantValueExpressionType: { retStr = [self SQLConstantForValue:[expression constantValue]];
                                         //NSLog(@"NSConstantValueExpressionType %@",retStr); // contains 'Patient Name' etc..
                                         break; }
        case NSVariableExpressionType: { retStr = [self SQLNamedReplacementVariableForVariable:[expression variable]];
                                         //NSLog(@"NSVariableExpressionType %@",retStr);
                                         break; }
         case NSKeyPathExpressionType: { retStr = [self SQLExpressionForKeyPath:[expression keyPath]];
                                         //NSLog(@"NSKeyPathExpressionType %@",retStr);
                                         break; }
        case NSFunctionExpressionType: { retStr = [self SQLFunctionLiteralForFunctionExpression:expression];
                                         //NSLog(@"NSFunctionExpressionType %@",retStr);
                                         break; }
        case NSSubqueryExpressionType: { retStr = [self SQLSelectClauseForSubqueryExpression:expression];
                                         //NSLog(@"NSSubqueryExpressionType %@",retStr);
                                         break; }
       case NSAggregateExpressionType: { retStr = [self SQLLiteralListForArray:[expression collection]];
                                         //PSLog(@"NSAggregateExpressionType %@",retStr);
                                         break; }
        case NSUnionSetExpressionType: { break; }
    case NSIntersectSetExpressionType: { break; }
        case NSMinusSetExpressionType: { break; }

 case NSEvaluatedObjectExpressionType: { break; } // these can't be converted 
           case NSBlockExpressionType: { break; }
        //case NSAnyKeyExpressionType: { break; }
  };
return retStr;
}

/*
- (NSString *) SQLInfixOperatorForOperatorType:(NSPredicateOperatorType) type
{
switch (type)
 {           case NSLessThanPredicateOperatorType: { return(@"<");
                                                     break; }
    case NSLessThanOrEqualToPredicateOperatorType: { return(@"<=");
                                                     break; }
          case NSGreaterThanPredicateOperatorType: { return(@">");
                                                     break; }
 case NSGreaterThanOrEqualToPredicateOperatorType: { return(@">=");
                                                     break; }
              case NSEqualToPredicateOperatorType: { return(@"=");
                                                     break; }
           case NSNotEqualToPredicateOperatorType: { return(@"<>");
                                                     break; }
              case NSMatchesPredicateOperatorType: { return(@"MATCH");
                                                     break; }
                   case NSInPredicateOperatorType: { return(@"IN");
                                                     break; }
              case NSBetweenPredicateOperatorType: { return(@"BETWEEN");
                                                     break; }
                 case NSLikePredicateOperatorType: { return(@"LIKE");
                                                     break; }
             case NSContainsPredicateOperatorType: { return(@"CONTAINS");
                                                     break; }
           case NSBeginsWithPredicateOperatorType:
             case NSEndsWithPredicateOperatorType: { //NSAssert(0,@"predicate not converted because 'beginswith' and 'endswith' are not consistently supported by SQL");
                                                     break; }
       case NSCustomSelectorPredicateOperatorType: { //NSAssert(0,@"predicate cannot be converted to a where clause because it calls a custom selector");
                                                     break; }
  };
return(nil);
}
*/

- (NSString *) SQLWhereClauseForComparisonPredicate:(NSComparisonPredicate *)predicate
{
NSString *leftSQLExpression  = [self SQLExpressionForLeftNSExpression:[predicate leftExpression]];
NSString *rightSQLExpression = [self SQLExpressionForNSExpression:[predicate rightExpression]];

switch ([predicate predicateOperatorType])
 {           case NSLessThanPredicateOperatorType: { return([NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@ < '%@')",leftSQLExpression,rightSQLExpression]);
                                                     break; }
    case NSLessThanOrEqualToPredicateOperatorType: { return([NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@ <= '%@')",leftSQLExpression,rightSQLExpression]);
                                                     break; }
          case NSGreaterThanPredicateOperatorType: { return([NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@ > '%@')",leftSQLExpression,rightSQLExpression]);
                                                     break; }
 case NSGreaterThanOrEqualToPredicateOperatorType: { return([NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@ >= '%@')",leftSQLExpression,rightSQLExpression]);
                                                     break; }
              case NSEqualToPredicateOperatorType: { return([NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@ = '%@')",leftSQLExpression,rightSQLExpression]);
                                                     break; }
           case NSNotEqualToPredicateOperatorType: { return([NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@ <> '%@')",leftSQLExpression,rightSQLExpression]);
                                                     break; }
              case NSMatchesPredicateOperatorType: { return([NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@ MATCH '%@')",leftSQLExpression,rightSQLExpression]);
                                                     break; }
                   case NSInPredicateOperatorType: { return([NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@ IN '%@')",leftSQLExpression,rightSQLExpression]);
                                                     break; }
              case NSBetweenPredicateOperatorType: { return([NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@ BETWEEN '%@' AND '%@')",[self SQLExpressionForLeftNSExpression:[predicate leftExpression]],
                      [self SQLExpressionForNSExpression:[[predicate rightExpression] collection][0]],
                      [self SQLExpressionForNSExpression:[[predicate rightExpression] collection][1]]]);
                                                     break; }
                 case NSLikePredicateOperatorType:
             case NSContainsPredicateOperatorType: { return([NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@ LIKE '%%%@%%')",leftSQLExpression,rightSQLExpression]);
                                                     break; }
           case NSBeginsWithPredicateOperatorType: { return([NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@ LIKE '%@%%')",leftSQLExpression,rightSQLExpression]);
                                                     break; }
             case NSEndsWithPredicateOperatorType: { return([NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@ LIKE '%%%@')",leftSQLExpression,rightSQLExpression]);
                                                     break; }
       case NSCustomSelectorPredicateOperatorType: { PSLog(@"SQLWhereClauseForComparisonPredicate custom selectors are not supported");
                                                     break; }
  };

/*
//NSAssert(0,@"predicate not converted because 'beginswith' and 'endswith' are not consistently supported by SQL");
//NSAssert(0,@"predicate cannot be converted to a where clause because it calls a custom selector");

NSString *comparator = [self SQLInfixOperatorForOperatorType:[predicate predicateOperatorType]];
if (comparator != nil)
   { if ([comparator isEqual:@"BETWEEN"])
      { return([NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@ %@ '%@' AND '%@')",[self SQLExpressionForLeftNSExpression:[predicate leftExpression]],comparator,
                      [self SQLExpressionForNSExpression:[[predicate rightExpression] collection][0]],
                      [self SQLExpressionForNSExpression:[[predicate rightExpression] collection][1]]]);

       }
 else { if ([comparator isEqual:@"CONTAINS"])
         { return([NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@ LIKE '%%%@%%')",[self SQLExpressionForLeftNSExpression:[predicate leftExpression]],
                      [self SQLExpressionForNSExpression:[predicate rightExpression]]]);
          }
    else { return([NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@ %@ '%@')",[self SQLExpressionForLeftNSExpression:[predicate leftExpression]],comparator,
                      [self SQLExpressionForNSExpression:[predicate rightExpression]]]);
          };
       };
   } else { PSLog(@"SQLWhereClauseForComparisonPredicate predicate could not be converted to comparator"); };
   */
return(nil);
}

- (NSString *) SQLWhereClauseForCompoundPredicate:(NSCompoundPredicate *)predicate
{
NSMutableArray *subs = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSPredicate *sub in [predicate subpredicates]) { [subs addObject:[self SQLFilterForPredicate:sub]]; };

NSString *conjunction;
switch ([(NSCompoundPredicate *)predicate compoundPredicateType])
 { case NSAndPredicateType: { conjunction = @" AND "; break; }
    case NSOrPredicateType: { conjunction = @" OR ";  break; }
   case NSNotPredicateType: { conjunction = @" NOT "; break; }
                   default: { conjunction = @" ";     break; }
 };

//NSLog(@"SQLWhereClauseForCompoundPredicate conjunction %@",conjunction);

return([NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@)", [subs componentsJoinedByString:conjunction]]);
}

- (NSString *)SQLFilterForPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate
{    
if ([predicate respondsToSelector:@selector(compoundPredicateType)])
      { return([self SQLWhereClauseForCompoundPredicate:(NSCompoundPredicate *)predicate]);
       }
 else { if ([predicate respondsToSelector:@selector(predicateOperatorType)])
         { return([self SQLWhereClauseForComparisonPredicate:(NSComparisonPredicate *)predicate]);
          }
    else { PSLog(@"SQLFilterForPredicate predicate is not of a convertible class");
          }
      };
return(nil);
}

@end
```

You can create your own database info like below in some global variable.

```
gDatabaseTitles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Name",@"Phone Number",@"Location",@"Date Of Birth",@"Miscellaneous",nil];

   gDatabaseKeys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name",@"phone_number",@"location",@"date_of_birth",@"misc",nil];

   gDatabaseTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name TEXT",@"phone_number TEXT",@"location TEXT",@"date_of_birth DATE",@"misc TEXT",nil];

   gDatabaseDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:gPatientDatabaseTitles forKeys:gPatientDatabaseKeys];
```

I had to edit a lot of the code to take out stuff related to my project, so this might not compile if I missed something, but this is the concept that works.  Let me know if you have any problems and I'll fix it up.  Anywhere you see gVariable is a global variable I'm referring to that helped me on my project and would probably help you.